# Import CSV file to postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql

I want to import large csv file its around 1GB of size using copy command.
But the condition is if lets see Column A1  datatype is Numeric and the data of the csv file is also of type numeric but some of the values are in alpha numeric. so its not importing .
What i want is set the non-numeric value of the colum A1 to null and import the data.
All the condition i want in the copy command .
Sample of csv file.

```html
<table border=true>
<tr>
<th >A1</th>
<th>A2</th>
<th>A3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>90</td>
<td>91</td>
<td>92</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>A21</td>
<td>B23</td>
<td>C43</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>12</td>
<td>13</td>
<td>14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>12ddwd3</td>
<td>1yhh53</td>
<td>1dfsf754</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>12</td>
<td>13</td>
<td>14</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Table meta data will be A1 numeric,A2 numeric,A3 numeric
I want to import csv file into the table and non numeric value will set to Null.

Comment: 1. import as text, 2. update set null where alphanumeric, 3. alter table alter columntype int

Comment: This is not a CSV file.

Comment: The input you show is XML, not CSV.

Comment: @vao Tsun ,i m also following the same approach but for the 1 million record its taking around 20-30 min . How to optimise the step 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

you cant conditionnaly `COPY` table from file. what you can do instead:

```
create table t (a1 text, a2 text, a3 text);
COPY t from file;
update t set a1 = null where a1 !~ '^\d{1,}$';
alter table t alter column a1 type int using a1::int;
```

Comment: if i follow this approach then for the 100 column of 1 million record its taking 20-30 min .Update and alter taking so much time .Need solution to optimise the query