# How can I remove tailing white space while loading data from CSV file into an Postgres Table?

Tags: postgresql, csv, postgresql-9.2

I want to remove the trailing whitespaces from CSV file.

Sample CSV file Data:**(Delimitor=";")**

`X ;Y;Z`

`X1  ; Y1;Z1`

`X2;Y2; Z2`

I would have gone for something like **SED** or **GREP** but the file size is huge so it may impact the performance because of preprocessing.

I am looking for a way to remove these whites spaces at the time of loading only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COPY` command does not support preprocessing - you can't do it "at the time of loading "

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

> In CSV format, all characters are significant. A quoted value
>   surrounded by white space, or any characters other than DELIMITER,
>   will include those characters. This can cause errors if you import
>   data from a system that pads CSV lines with white space out to some
>   fixed width. If such a situation arises you might **need to preprocess
>   the CSV file to remove the trailing white space, before importing the
>   data into PostgreSQL**.

I think here the best solution would be importing data with spaces and then

```
update t set attr = rtim(attr);
```

Comment: Do you have any optimised way to do this at the time of preprocessing?

Comment: I just answered a very similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/47324806/5315974 - import with space and then update removong it

Comment: Even for importing with spaces I am getting this error
`ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xa0`

Comment: Regarding this issue, you would probably have to check here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867272/invalid-byte-sequence-for-encoding-utf8

Comment: @AkshayPatil encoding not matching for you csv file content and db settings is not related to OP

Comment: This error is coming because of the white spaces in file.